# Firebase notification click ios don't opening application

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the application we developed with flutter, when we click on the notification on the android side, the application should open and redirect to a page. While this part works on the Android side, it does not work on the iOS side.

When we watch the application in debug mode, it gives an error "Received an invalid notification content" and at the same time we get an error like BAD_ACCESS. What would be the reason ?

Comment: By any chance have you used awesome notifications?

Comment: Yes I am using awesome notifications for foreground notifications. But the result does not change. There is a different problem and only on iOS.

Comment: Go through this comment I had made on this issue in the awesome notification. Very pesky issue. I am now using flutter local notifications instead, that works. https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications/issues/365#issuecomment-1000043177

Comment: First of all, thank you for my suggestion. But there is a situation like this, we are using firebase_messaging compulsorily. The reason we use this is because we are sending a message from the cloud when the application is closed. So unfortunately we don't have a chance to change it until we find a different cloud notification plugin. We don't have a problem for local notifications anyway, the only problem is that when the notification is clicked, it doesn't run the application on the iOS side.

Comment: What I'm saying is to replace awesome notification with flutter local notification. firebase_messaging can stay